# Can't inspect objects in Spyder created using imported modules

Tags: python, spyder

I have a python script that uses a class definition from a module in a subdirectory of my project. My main module code looks like this:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('main_module_folder/helper_folder/')
import helper_module as h

test = h.Foo()
```

The helper module, which contains the class definition, looks like this:

```
class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        var1 = 'foo'
```

When I run the main module, the code executes fine. But if I try to inspect the "test" object using the variable explorer in Spyder, I get an error saying "Spyder is unable to show the variable you're trying to view because the module *helper_module* was not found in the Spyder environment".

However, starting from a fresh Ipython instance, if I run "helper_module.py" first, and then modify my main module to remove the import:

```
# import sys
# sys.path.append('main_module_folder/helper_folder/')
# import helper_module as h

test = Foo()
```

Then I can use the variable explorer to inspect the variable just fine. Why is this? Is there some clean way to import stuff into the main module and still have the objects viewable in the object explorer? I'm running Spyder 4.1.5

Comment: Because you are dynamically modifying the path: `sys.path.append('main_module_folder/helper_folder/')` which really isn't what you should be doing to begin with. But apparently, spyder requires the name to be available for it to work with the variable explorer.

Comment: So what's the best way to call a module that's not in the same folder as the main module? I've also used os.chdir() to switch to the helper module directory and then run the import statement, but this also seems kind of clunky.